# How to check and set values of specific value object inside a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I Have a method in a repository class that sets insert metadata for a domain object:

```
 private void SetInsertMetadata(TDomainEntity entity)
 {
      entity.InsertDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
 }
```

I Need to check – does this `entity` class have a list of value objects as properties? If so, then set `InsertDT` in each of them.

How do I do this check from generic class?

Comment: Does `TDomainEntity` implement an interface that defines the relevant properties?

Comment: Are you saying that if, for example, `entity.SomeProperty` also implements `TDomainEntity` then set the `InsertDT` property on that too?

Comment: If you can't rely on an interface you can delegate to class itself (!) or use Reflection (!!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some assumptions here. First that your interface looks like this:

```
public interface TDomainEntity
{
    DateTime InsertDT { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a couple of entities:

```
public class EntityA : TDomainEntity
{
    public EntityB BValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDT { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : TDomainEntity
{
    public DateTime InsertDT { get; set; }
}
```

Your function to loop through every property and set the `InsertDT` property could be something like this:

```
private void SetInsertMetadata(TDomainEntity entity)
{
    if(entity == null) return;  //To prevent errors below

    entity.InsertDT = DateTime.UtcNow;

    //Get all properties of the entity that also implement the TDomainEntity interface
    var props = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => typeof(TDomainEntity).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));

    //Recurse through each property:
    foreach(var p in props)
    {
        SetInsertMetadata((TDomainEntity)p.GetValue(entity));
    }
}
```

Or you could merge those last lines together:

```
entity.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => typeof(TDomainEntity).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => SetInsertMetadata((TDomainEntity)p.GetValue(entity)));
```

If you also want to include`IEnumerable<TDomainEntity>` properties, add this:

```
entity.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => typeof(IEnumerable<TDomainEntity>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => 
    {
        var value = (IEnumerable<TDomainEntity>)p.GetValue(entity);
        if(value == null) return;
        value.ToList().ForEach(i => SetInsertMetadata((TDomainEntity)i));
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please help me with enhancing your code with case when EntityA has a property as IList<EntityB>?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class definition looks a bit like:

```
public class GenericClass<TDomainEntity>
{
    ...
}
```

You want to specify that TDomainEntity inherits from an interface. Create an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IDateTimeHolder
{
    DateTime InsertTD { get; set; }
}
```

(Name the interface however you want)
Then update your generic class to specify the interface for the generic type:

```
public class GenericClass<TDomainEntity> where TDomainEntity : IDateTimeHolder
{
    string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Also makes sure that the class passed in implements the interface.